# How to integrate Custom Courier in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, countries

I want to integrate DTDC couriers on my project website. But the courier agency didn't provides the api for integration.So I want to know How to manually integrate the courier service, and how to manage it.

Thanks

Comment: for what purpose you need this.you need to add tracking numbers for the orders manually ?

Comment: for both orders and tracking @PradeepSanku

Comment: @Gayathri, Did you integrated DTDC into your store? Is there any extension available?